# Is it possible in Durandal 1.2 to map route navs with parameters?

Tags: navigation, durandal

I'm using Durandal 1.2 and have a nav bar like this:

[image]

I want to do the following:

- The dropdown is a list of customers, and the user can select any of
  them
- If none are selected, the first is considered the default.
- The other links in the navbar should have urls matching the customer id.
- The **Details**-page should also be the landing page.

So for the default customer, the urls would be:

- `company/1/details`
- `company/1/orders`

Selecting a different customer would give

- `company/2/details`
- `company/2/orders`

Here's what I can't figure out how to do:

1. The very first time the user lands, I don't know the customer id and
   there are no navs to map. What I want to do then, is to pick the
   default customer, map the navs and navigate to the landing page
   (`customer/1/details`).
2. The navs should now be mapped with the default customer id.
3. When the user select a different customer, the navs should be
   remapped with the selected customer id, but the user should **not**
   be navigated away from the current page. So if the user visited
   Customer #1's order page, then selected Customer #2, he should see
   Customer #2's order page.

**Update:**
I tried to map and redirect in `router.handleInvalidRoute`:

```
router.handleInvalidRoute = function(route, params) {
    router.mapNav("customer/1/details", "viewmodels/details", "details");
    router.navigateTo("#/customer/1/details");
};
```

The redirect works, but `mapNav` doesn't. The link is missing from the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `navigateTo` function on the router that should do what you're wanting.

Judging by your description, I'm assuming that details and orders are on separate pages.

In Durandal, you'll normally have the page (view-model) name followed by the parameters.  So for this answer, I'm going to assume the page names of customer-details and customer-orders, each having an id parameter.

In that case, you'll need a route set up that handles the parameters like this:

```
router.mapNav("customer-details/:id");
router.mapNav("customer-details");
router.mapNav("customer-orders/:id");
```

With this mapping, you should be able to navigate to the customer-details page with or without an id.

As far as I know, Durandal 1.x doesn't really have support for re-navigating from within the activate function.  As a result, you might consider:

1. Allowing route without an id specified, but not forcing it to re-navigate to an id-specific route.
2. Getting the default customer id prior to navigating to the details page.

Assuming option 1:

In the activate function, you can check to see if an id was passed:

```
function activate(context){
    //load the customer dropdown source
    ...

    if( !context.hasOwnProperty("id") ){
        //id was not supplied, so set the current customer id 
        //  to the first one in the customer dropdown source
        ...
    }
}
```

---

As for the nav bar, it might be easiest to set up the nav links so they are generic.  You can bind the link's click to a function in the view model, and programatically navigate from there.  That way you can apply any necessary logic.

view

```
//in the view
<select data-bind='options: customers, value: selectedCustomer'></select>

<a data-bind='click: showDetails'>Details</a>
| <a data-bind='click: showOrders'>Orders</a>
```

view model

```
//in the view model  
//   (these members need to be expose publically so knockout can access them)

var customers = ko.observableArray();
var selectedCustomer = ko.observable();

function showDetails(){
    if( this.selectedCustomer() ){
        var id = this.selectedCustomer().id;
        router.navigateTo("#/customer-details/" + id);
    }
}; 
function showOrders(){
    if( this.selectedCustomer() ){
        var id = this.selectedCustomer().id;
        router.navigateTo("#/customer-orders/" + id);
    }
};
```

Hopefully this helps - it's not 100%, but should give you some ideas anyway.

Comment: Details and orders are just an example, but yes, they are separate pages / views / viewmodels. I have thought about your suggestion, to turn the nav links into link-buttons, but it's not that easy. If I do that, I also have to account for whether the nav is active or not.